# JS inside PHP Escape String (for functions)

Tags: php, javascript, escaping

I have a `PHP` script that generates some `Javascript` for me in a manner like this:

```
foreach ($array as $element)
{
    echo '<a onClick="myFunctionTakesPHPValues('.$element[0].','.$element[1].')">'.$element[2].'</a>';
}
```

My problem is that how can I escape so that the Javascript bit will look more like

```
<a onClick='MyFunctionTakesPHPValues("'.$element[0].','.$element[1].'")>'.$element[2].'</a>';
```

I hope this makes sense. The short version is that I feel i need triple quotes inside double quotes inside single quotes, but there is no such thing as triple quotes, but I believe there is some way to escape quotes to nest it up three times.

Comment: Use backslash before your string-delimiter quotes. `\'` or `\"`

Comment: -1. Nothing personal but just to make this question less relevant in search

Comment: I can understand that, however judging from your comments to the other answer and the answer that is more or less the same as it could imply that there are many people out there with security breaches as a result of not understanding this properly. Cheers for your answer though. Would `htmlspecialchars` be as safe as `json_encode`, I seem to get quotes around all my strings when I use `json_encode` but not with `htmlspecialchars`. And I could only properly use `json_encode` as attributes in the `onClick` function as in your example.

Comment: Look, you have two medias in your short code snippet - a JS code and HTML code. Each require **different** formatting (as explained in the article I linked to) - so, that's why two functions were used.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, think I understand it now :)

Comment: Well actually I was wrong.

Comment: Have a look at this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript . Putting onclick in html and echoing js from php is bad practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Never echo JS from PHP. Escape from PHP mode instead, it will save you a lot of slashes and nerves.
2. Every value have to be escaped properly, as explained in [this article](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

So, for the JS values you have to escape them with `json_encode()` **and**, as they are going into HTML attribute, escape them as HTML too.
For the last element only HTML encoding is required.

```
foreach ($array as $element) 
{
    $param1 = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($element[0])); // better give them 
    $param2 = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($element[1])); // meaningful names
    $param3 = htmlspecialchars($element[2]);
?>
<a onClick="myFunctionTakesPHPValues(<?=$param1?>,<?=$param2?>)">
   <?=$param3?>
</a>
<? }
```

And yes, using raw JS in HTML attributes considered as a bad practice.

Answer (score 3):

Same as always: encode as JSON.

```
echo '<a onClick="myFunctionTakesPHPValues('.json_encode($element[0]).','.json_encode($element[1]).')">'.$element[2].'</a>';
```

Comment: This works nicely too, however my string variables come up with quotes now, does that just mean I have too many quotes in there?

Comment: You shouldn't need to add any quotes to the values manually; JSON strings are valid JavaScript literals.

Comment: It turned out that you actually have to.

Answer (score 1):

Use Like

```
echo "<a onClick='myFunctionTakesPHPValues(\"".$element[0]."\",\"".$element[1]."\")'>".$element[2]."</a>";
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, I was doing my escape slashes the opposite way >_< Cheers to all answers.

Comment: @Tom actually this is an awfully wrong answer. Making your code insecure

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
echo "<a onClick='MyFunctionTakesPHPValues(\"'".$element[0]."','".$element[1]."'\")>'".$element[2]."'</a>'";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array as $element)
{?>
<a onClick="myFunctionTakesPHPValues("<?php echo $element[0].','.$element[1].')>'.$element[2].'</a>'
} 
?>
```